# Why in CodeIgniter redirect function is not working on live server, but working fine on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

After Installation. I set the login as default controller and want to go to dashboard of admin but after submitting login details instead of redirecting to the dashboard, it is redirecting to install controller again.

can anyone help me?

My login controller is login.php:

```php
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller
{


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }

    /***default functin, redirects to login page if no admin logged in yet***/
    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');

        if ($this->session->userdata('doctor_login') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?doctor/dashboard', 'refresh');

        if ($this->session->userdata('patient_login') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?patient/dashboard', 'refresh');

        if ($this->session->userdata('nurse_login') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?nurse/dashboard', 'refresh');

        if ($this->session->userdata('pharmacist_login') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?pharmacist/dashboard', 'refresh');

        if ($this->session->userdata('laboratorist_login') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?laboratorist/dashboard', 'refresh');

        if ($this->session->userdata('accountant_login') == 1)
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?accountant/dashboard', 'refresh');



        $config = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'login_type',
                'label' => 'Account Type',
                'rules' => 'required|xss_clean'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required|xss_clean|valid_email'
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'required|xss_clean|callback__validate_login'
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_validate_login', ucfirst($this->input->post('login_type')) . ' Login failed!');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>', '</div>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login');
        } else {
            if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');

            if ($this->session->userdata('doctor_login') == 1)
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?doctor/dashboard', 'refresh');

            if ($this->session->userdata('patient_login') == 1)
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?patient/dashboard', 'refresh');

            if ($this->session->userdata('nurse_login') == 1)
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?nurse/dashboard', 'refresh');

            if ($this->session->userdata('pharmacist_login') == 1)
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?pharmacist/dashboard', 'refresh');

            if ($this->session->userdata('laboratorist_login') == 1)
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?laboratorist/dashboard', 'refresh');

            if ($this->session->userdata('accountant_login') == 1)
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?accountant/dashboard', 'refresh');
        }

    }

    /***validate login****/
    function _validate_login($str)
    {
        if ($this->input->post('login_type') == '') {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('login_failed'));
            return FALSE;
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->input->post('login_type'), array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        ));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'admin') {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'admin');
                $this->session->set_userdata('admin_login', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id', $row->admin_id);
            }
            if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'doctor') {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'doctor');
                $this->session->set_userdata('doctor_login', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('doctor_id', $row->doctor_id);
            }
            if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'patient') {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'patient');
                $this->session->set_userdata('patient_login', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('patient_id', $row->patient_id);
            }
            if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'nurse') {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'nurse');
                $this->session->set_userdata('nurse_login', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('nurse_id', $row->nurse_id);
            }
            if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'pharmacist') {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'pharmacist');
                $this->session->set_userdata('pharmacist_login', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('pharmacist_id', $row->pharmacist_id);
            }
            if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'laboratorist') {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'laboratorist');
                $this->session->set_userdata('laboratorist_login', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('laboratorist_id', $row->laboratorist_id);
            }
            if ($this->input->post('login_type') == 'accountant') {
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'accountant');
                $this->session->set_userdata('accountant_login', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('accountant_id', $row->accountant_id);
            }
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('login_failed'));
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    /*******LOGOUT FUNCTION *******/
    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata();
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('logged_out'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?login', 'refresh');
    }

    /***DEFAULT NOR FOUND PAGE*****/
    function four_zero_four()
    {
        $this->load->view('four_zero_four');
    }

    /***RESET AND SEND PASSWORD TO REQUESTED EMAIL****/
    function reset_password()
    {
        $account_type = $this->input->post('account_type');
        if ($account_type == "") {
            redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
        }
        $email  = $this->input->post('email');
        $result = $this->email_model->password_reset_email($account_type, $email); //SEND EMAIL ACCOUNT OPENING EMAIL
        if ($result == true) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('password_sent'));
        } else if ($result == false) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('account_not_found'));
        }


    }

    /***LOGIN AS ANOTHER USER LIKE DOCTOR,PATIENT,PHARMACIST,LABORATORIST ETC******/
    function login_as($user_type = '', $user_id = '')
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', $user_type);
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_type . '_login', '1');
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_type . '_id', $user_id);
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?' . $user_type . '/dashboard', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: did u load helper url?

Comment: $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: How to write your function?

Comment: yes i load helper in autoload.php

Comment: what could be the reason as it is working on localhost not on live server???

Comment: you need to add the htaccess  and remove this index.php from url then it's work fine

Comment: from whre can i get .htaccess file

Comment: (RTFM!) It's a [first page](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file) on General Topics in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the cookie in the live server? I had experienced something similar like yours. The `redirect()` function was not work in live server, but in fact the thing which doesn't work well was the `user_data` session has gone everytime page loaded. I just allowed the cookie `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = "MY-COOKIE*******"` in live server and everything goes well.